# Replacing strings with sed in ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

I have a config file with such value:

```
SITE_URL=http://domain.com
```

So I am trying to replace it with something like development.local.dev with sed, but not sure how to escape the domain correctly. Tried a lot of something like this:

```
sed -i -e 's/SITE_URL=http://domain\.com/SITE_URL=development.local.dev/g' .env
```

But keep getting: sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `/` is used a regex delimiter and it is used in your search pattern as well.

You can use an alternate delimiter e.g. `~` in `sed`:

```
sed '/^SITE_URL=/s~http://domain\.com~development.local.dev~' file
SITE_URL=development.local.dev
```

Comment: That actually helped. Thanks!